# Running sh script non rooted

Tags: applications, rooting, bluetooth, mac-address

I am not a developer and I have an application that I need to run on my Samsung 10+ which uses a plugin developed for the app to receive sensor data from a separate android device via Bluetooth connection. The Samsung 10+ is typically connected to the sensor via the Bluetooth MAC address. As the sensor data is received it is displayed on a map overlay on the Samsung. I don't have the actual sensor, as I don't need it for my purposes, but I have a script which can be run which is supposed to output representative data so that when I connect the two devices I should see the data displayed. What I need help with is identifying how you actually run a script on an android if you are not a superuser. Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For executing scripts there are two possibilities:

### Via Android Debug Bridge (adb)

ADB is usually used when the device is connected via USB to a PC. But for trusted Wifis there is a also a possibility to run ADB over Wifi (but the connection is play-text like terinal which may lead to security problems, therefore the limitation to trused Wifis). Then you can execute a script that is e.g. saved in `/data/local`

### Use an app like Termux

Apps like [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux) provide an environment similar to a Linux distribution with packet manager and execution environment. You don't need a connected PC. However as Termux is an app the Android permission system applies you may get a problem accessing the Bluetooth hardware as Termux as far as I remember does not requests the Bluetooth permissions on installation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I was not able to use adb, but like Termux.

Comment: @Adrian you can accept and/or upvote the answer if it worked for you so that it's more helpful for future visitors. Thank you.